# Union type doesn't allow if statement with Typescript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have code that is something like this

```js
// some package
export interface TCustomer {
  name: string;
}
```

```js
import { TCustomer } from "some-package"

interface BCustomer extends TCustomer {
  options: string;
}

type Props = {
  customers: TCustomer[] | BCustomer[];
};

const CustomersTable: React.FC<Props> = ({ customers }) => {

  return customers.map(customer => (
    <div>
      {customer.options && <span>{customer.name}</span>}
      <span>{customer.name}</span>
    </div>
  )
)}
```

Typescript doesn't like that `customer.options` doesn't exist on the imported type of `TCustomer`. That makes sense to me and is true. What I don't understand is why? I'm handling the "type" by using `&&` so my intuition is that TS should see that I know that this "might" be undefined.

What is typescript trying to enforce here, and how can I write an if statement on a union type in a more Typescript way?

I'm aware that I "could" write:

```js
interface BCustomer extends TCustomer {
  options: string;
}
interface CCustomer extends TCustomer {
  options?: undefined;
}

type Props = {
  customers: CCustomer[] | BCustomer[];
};
```

But this seems unneccesary when I could handle the this internally to the component. It seems odd to add a field to a type that shouldn't have that field. However, this may be the "correct" way to do it. If that's the case that's fine. If that's the case I would like to understand why TS is this way so that I can write better TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly access a property if TypeScript can't determine that the property *definitely* exists. Even if you're only accessing it to check for truthyness, it's not allowed, unfortunately. Here, you can use `in` instead. (Using `in` is not only permitted, it'll also let TS narrow the type for use later - while not useful *here* since you aren't using any `BCustomer`-specific properties, it's a good technique to know.)

```
{'options' in customer && <span>{customer.name}</span>}
```

Since you only need JavaScript logic and not TypeScript narrowing here, you could also use

```
{customer.hasOwnProperty('options') && <span>{customer.name}</span>}
```

Even if `{customer.options &&` was permitted, it might be a mistake, because not all customers with a falsey `options` will be a `TCustomer` - it might be a `BCustomer` with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a reasonable solution. I'm not quite sure I like this but I'll get over it. Appreciate your time!